# Linear programming optimization problems using parallel algorithms

Tags: linear-programming, convex-optimization, parallel

I'm looking for methods and algorithms for solving linear programming algorithms, characterized by up to 20 variables but up to thousands of constraints in a parallel way. There are several approaches for solving LP problems in a parallel way, but I wonder if there are specific methods which are efficient for such (real-world, by the way) systems.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would expect that linear programs of that size should be easily solvable using standard (sequential) LP algorithms/implementations.  It's still an interesting question whether there are good ways to take advantage of parallelism, in general.

Comment: In general, linear programming is P-complete, so it's unlikely to have very efficient parallel algorithms.

Comment: Like D.W. mentioned, that size LP is easily solved. Even LPs with millions of variables/constraints are routinely solved (usually with sparse constraint matrices). On the practical side, [Benders' decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benders%27_decomposition) is used to solve large LPs that have special structure. Many times the subproblems can be solved in parallel.